# games.filter is not a function || React hooks component not receiving data

Tags: javascript, react-hooks, use-state, react-component, use-context

Up till this point, I have been able to fetch my data from MongoDB and view the data in my frontend console in react but `games.filter` is stopping my component from receiving the data and display them in the browser.

I have tried using `Object.values(games).filter`; the error goes away but it doesn't display the data still.

Here is a screenshot when i inspected the components
[I can see the data in GamesByCategory component here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qU6Se.png)

Here's is another image:

[Datas in GamesBox is `undefined`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uz1hs.png)

Here's my code

```
import React, {useState, useRef, useContext} from 'react'
import { useScrollPosition } from '@n8tb1t/use-scroll-position'
import GameBox from '../objects/GameBox'
import  GamesContext  from '../../contexts/GamesContext'




const GamesByCategories = () => {

    const { games, setGames } = useContext(GamesContext)
    const [currentCategory, setCurrentCategory] = useState(0)
    
    const [categories, setCategories] = useState([
        {id: 0, name: 'all', isActive: true},
        {id: 1, name: 'gadgets', isActive: false},
        {id: 2, name: 'sports', isActive: false},
        {id: 3, name: 'family', isActive: false},
    ])

    const categoriesTab = categories.map(category => {
        var active = category.isActive ? 'active' : ''
        return(
            <div key={category.id} onClick={() => filterCategory(category.id)} className={"tab-element " + active } >
                <span>{category.name}</span>
            </div>
        )
    })


    //filter and populate the games list by current category

  // THIS IS WHERE I AM HAVING ISSUES
    const gamesList = Object.values(games).filter(game => !game.isVersion )        
        .filter(game => (game.category === (currentCategory) || currentCategory === 0))
         .map(game => {
            return (
             <GameBox id={game.id} image={game.image} name={game.name} price={game.price} isNew={game.gameIsNew} /> 
                )
         }) 

    const filterCategory = (categoryId) => {

        //update the current category
        var updatedCategories = categories.map(category => {
            if(category.id === categoryId){
                category.isActive = true
                
            }else{
                category.isActive = false
            }

            return category
        })

        setCurrentCategory(categoryId)

        setCategories(updatedCategories)
        
    }

    //add some styles to sticky categories tab
    const [isCategoriesTabSticky, setIsCategoriesTabSticky] = useState(false)
    const categoriesTabRef = useRef(null)
    const stickyStyles = isCategoriesTabSticky ? "is-sticky" : ""

    useScrollPosition( ({currPos}) =>{
        if(-(currPos.y) >= categoriesTabRef.current.offsetTop){
            setIsCategoriesTabSticky(true)
        }else{
            setIsCategoriesTabSticky(false)
        }
    })

    return (
        <div>

            <div id="game-categories-tab" ref={categoriesTabRef} className={"flex justify-center mt-10 mb-8 custom-tabs " + stickyStyles}>
                <div className="tab-container">
                    <div className="flex">
                        {categoriesTab}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="grid justify-center  categories-games">
                <div className="flex flex-wrap justify-center categories-games-container">
                    { gamesList }
                </div> 
            </div>

            
        </div>
    )
}


export default GamesByCategories;
```

Kindly reach-out and help.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Replace Object.values(games).filter with games.data.filter

Comment: I'm agree with  @soltex 
And you put `!game.isVersion` in your code and in your console screenshoot we can see `isVerOrient` is this a typo ?

Comment: Thank you for reaching out @soltex, I changed it as instructed and it returns: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined`

Comment: @antoineso Thank you for pointing it out, i have corrected it.

Comment: You need to make sure your games.data array exists before you use the filter property.

Comment: @soltex now it says `data is not defined` can you suggest a way to go about it?

Comment: From the output gotten from screenshot provided i should be able to access games.data, what am i doing wrong here?